# Изменение цветов в Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Я хочу кастомизировать свой Windows 10. Нашел программу "редактор реестра" и папку colors в ней. Но никак не могу понять за что какой файл отвечает. Фон в проводнике и цвет текста вообще никак не могу поменять. Кто знает как это сделать, пожалуйста подскажите.